# Add image with sign in button in bot MS Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

i am using OAuthPromptSettings to display a simple button. but now i want to display an image above and then display the "Sign in " button on MS Teams.
I have a simple "Sign in" button.
I do not know how to display an image along with this button.

Comment: You need to provide details on what you have already tried

Comment: Could you please provide more details on this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to add image in oauth card or add oauth in a hero card so that an image can be added

Answer (score 0):

If you are using predefined sign-in button from Microsoft Auth, it's not possible for us to add the image directly on it.

But if you are using your own custom button then I think you can show a image on it.